# Переименование файлов

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Как сделать такое задание: Перед каждым именем файла (regular file) вставить его номер (1, 2, 3 и т. д.). Номер выставляется в соответствии с тем, в каком порядке выдает результаты функция FindFirstFile, FindNextFile.

Смог сделать только это:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<tchar.h>
using namespace std;

//strcpy, strcat
//_tcscpy,_tcscat

int main()
{
 DWORD dwError = 0;
setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
WIN32_FIND_DATA find;
HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(_T("C:\\test\\*"), &find);
{
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFind)
    {
        cout << "Каталог не найден!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        return dwError;
    }
    do {
        if (!(find.dwFileAttributes == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) && !(find.dwFileAttributes == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVICE))
            _tprintf(_T("%s\n"), find.cFileName);
    } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &find) != NULL);
    dwError = GetLastError();
    if (dwError == ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
    {
        FindClose(hFind);
        cout << "В каталоге нет файлов!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        return dwError;
    }
}////нет проверки на успешность FindFirstFile
FindClose(hFind); ////нет проверки на успешность FindClose
cout << "Файлы выведены на экран" << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

А как переименовывать файлы не понимаю

Answer (score 4):

Для переименования файлов есть сишная функция [rename()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw5t957f.aspx)

```
int rename(const char *old_filename, const char *new_filename)
```

или апишная [MoveFile()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa365239(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
BOOL WINAPI MoveFile(
  _In_ LPCTSTR lpExistingFileName,
  _In_ LPCTSTR lpNewFileName
);
```

Но учтите, что переименовывать файлы внутри цикла `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile` нельзя. Иначе цикл будет находить новые файлы.

Вам нужно в этом цикле сложить все имена файлов в массив, вызвать `FindClose()`, а потом пробежаться по этому массиву и переименовать файлы

Comment: Всё равно не будет работать правильно, если при этом кто-то другой что-то делает в каталоге. По-хорошему надо настроить нотификацию на события в каталоге, потом запустить монитор этих событий, параллельно переименовывая файлы. Вышеприведенное просто не атомарно.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку в вашем коде есть функция `system("pause")` то не грех ей и воспользоваться:

```
system("rename " + old_name + " " + new_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Файлы переименовываются функцией [MoveFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa365239.aspx).

> Функция MoveFile перемещает (переименовывает) файл или каталог (включая его дочерние элементы), или в том же самом каталоге, или во всех каталогах.